# Retrieve and Rank sample (Watson service) and Android

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I was trying to made a simple project with Retrieve and Rank service from IBM Watson. I have already a Collection, Cluster, and the Ranker is trained . Later I want to made a question to my service but I have problems with dependencies from org.apache.httcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1, there is no some classes. I've tried follow these examples:

1. https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/?java#query_standard
2. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/retrieve-and-rank
3. github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/examples/retrieve-and-rank-solrj/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/retrieve_and_rank/RetrieveAndRankSolrJExample.java

but I can't get anything, only the clusters list.

In gradle config I have two warnings :

> WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>
> WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Do you have any idea? this is my code:

**Gradle:App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testrnr"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.5.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    //compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:5.5.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**And this is my MainActivity class:**

```
package com.example.testrnr;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.retrieve_and_rank.v1.RetrieveAndRank;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthState;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;

import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpCoreContext;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String USERNAME_CLUSTER = "**********";
private static final String PASSWORD_CLUSTER = "**********";
private static final String SOLR_CLUSTER_ID = "**********";
private static final String RANKER_ID = "**********";
private static final String COLLECTION_N= "**********";

private static HttpSolrClient solrClient;
private static RetrieveAndRank service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    service = new RetrieveAndRank();
                    service.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME_CLUSTER, PASSWORD_CLUSTER);

                    Log.d("APP_TestRnR", "Clusters: " + service.getSolrClusters().execute());

                    solrClient = getSolrClient(service.getSolrUrl(SOLR_CLUSTER_ID), USERNAME_CLUSTER, PASSWORD_CLUSTER);
                    //SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
                    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
                    query.setQuery("Que es la gripe?");
                    query.setParam("ranker_id", RANKER_ID);

                    QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(COLLECTION_N, query);
                    Log.d("APP_TestRnR", "--RESPUESTA--" + response);

                } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }}).start();

    }

    private static HttpSolrClient getSolrClient(String uri, String username, String password) {
        return new HttpSolrClient(service.getSolrUrl(SOLR_CLUSTER_ID), createHttpClient(uri, username, password));
    }

    private static HttpClient createHttpClient(String uri, String username, String password) {
        final URI scopeUri = URI.create(uri);

        final BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(scopeUri.getHost(), scopeUri.getPort()),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("{username}", "{password}"));

        final HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setMaxConnTotal(128)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(32)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT).setRedirectsEnabled(true).build())
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .addInterceptorFirst(new PreemptiveAuthInterceptor());
        return builder.build();
    }

    private static class PreemptiveAuthInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
        public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
            final AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);

            if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
                final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context
                        .getAttribute(HttpClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
                final HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(HttpCoreContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
                final Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(),
                        targetHost.getPort()));
                if (creds == null) {
                    throw new HttpException("No creds provided for preemptive auth.");
                }

                authState.update(new BasicScheme(), creds); //**problems here** at update method

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android Studio says that this classes are deprecated: HttpClient, BasicCredentialsProvider, UsernamePasswordCredentials, AuthState, CredentialsProvider, Credentials, BasicScheme

Comment: Check Android Studio and find out what those classes were deprecated for.  There should be some mention of what replaces those.